How to make Windows Universal App with Javascript + Html in Visual Studio 2022
I have a bunch of apps I made in Visual Studio 2017 - I need to edit one, but unfortunately I haven't been able to find a way to install Visual Studio 2017 Community, so I decided the next best thing is to install Visual Studio 2022 Community and migrate my Universal Windows apps over.
I installed Community 2022, but I can't seem to find the right set of things to install in order to make UWP Apps in Html + Javascript
I tried following this guide, and at about 2:46 it shows a screen with an option for Universal Windows Platform Development - when I get to that screen on my computer, it doesn't say that, it says "Windows Application Development" instead. So I install that, but afterward I still don't have any new-project templates that look like they match the Javascript+Html Universal apps I had in 2017.

"UWP JavaScript apps are no longer supported in Visual Studio 2019."

@RaymondChen wow, that sucks! I have all these apps and no way to edit them.

As Raymond said, UWP JavaScript apps are no longer supported in Visual Studio 2019.
But older versions require an active Visual Studio Subscription. If you have a paid subscription, you will have access to the Visual Studio 2017 Downloads & Keys - Visual Studio Subscriptions

That's a shame, I think uwp JavaScript apps were really accessible. I basically learned how to program making those things. Thanks for the response.
